# Check webview elements inside a hybrid app

Tags: android, android-webview, android-espresso

I'm new to Espresso. I was wondering if there's a way to verify webview elements inside a hybird app. example: there's a button which after clicked an html page shows up, how to verify the content(say there's a shopping page, and what to verify is the showing price on it). How can I make all of these steps into only one test case? Much appreciated in advance.

**Here is what I tried but failed:**

**The code:**

```
public  class EspressoTest {
@Rule
public IntentsTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule =
        new IntentsTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);
@Test
public void testMembershipCenter(){
    //click user profile button to access shopping center
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    onView(withId(R.id.tv_main_username)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.tv_vip)).perform(click());
   //actually, I can see the shopping center is showing up on the real device
    onWebView().forceJavascriptEnabled();
    onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH,"//span[@class='orginal']")).check(webMatches(getText(),containsString("10")));
    onView(withId(R.id.ivBack)).perform(click());
    Log.i("taggggg","AAAA");
    }
}
```

**The error:**

```
Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.''. Check device logcat for details
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'
```

Officer https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/web.html shows only the pure webview examples right? or I have made misunderstanding.

Hope someone can show me some example code, Thanks again.:)